# is it possible to make certain part of the JsonFormat datetime optional?

Tags: java, json, date, datetime, format

I have a field which is defined with the seconds part, (i.e.: "ss") as follows

```
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z")
private Date date;
```

Is it possible to make the seconds part optional? so that both the following date String will work:

- "2020-02-13T16:02:11 EST" will be parsed to "Thu Feb 13 16:02:11 EST 2020"
- "2020-02-13T16:02 EST" will be parsed to "Thu Feb 13 16:02 EST 2020"

I am thinking about somethinglike (this does not work though...):
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm[:ss] z"

thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use the `Date` class? That class is poorly designed and long outdated. I’d try `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And do you need to depend on a three letter time zone abbreviation? `EST` is ambiguous, so I don’t think you can be sure what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

1. add a customerized Deserializer class 'DateDeserializer.class'
2. the DateDeserializer.class implement both pattern with and without the second part.

code sample is attched:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z")




public class DateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

private static final SimpleDateFormat withSeconds = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z");
private static final SimpleDateFormat withoutSeconds = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm z");

public DateDeserializer() {
    this(null);
}

public DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}

@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String dateString = p.getText();
    if (dateString.isEmpty()) {
        //handle empty strings however you want,
        //but I am setting the Date objects null
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return withSeconds.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        try {
            return withoutSeconds.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse date", e1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. And it’s not thread-safe, so if you nevertheless want to use don’t store it into static fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated and also not thread-safe, I thought I’d show you how to solve your task with java.time, the modern Java date and time API. For now I am assuming that you cannot change the type of your `date` field, it needs to be `Date`, and also that you cannot change the format/s. I rewrote the class from your own answer in this way:

```
public class DateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm[:ss] z", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public DateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String dateString = p.getText();
        if (dateString.isEmpty()) {
            //handle empty strings however you want,
            //but I am setting the Date objects null
            return null;
        }

        Instant parsedInstant = formatter.parse(dateString, Instant::from);
        return Date.from(parsedInstant);
    }
}
```

In the format pattern string I am using square brackets, `[]`, around the optional seconds of the minute. `DateTimeFormatter` is thread-safe (opposite `SimpleDateFormat`), so it is safe to have just one static instance even if used from several threads. `DateTimeFormatter.parse()` throws a runtime exception (unchecked exception) if it cannot parse the string, so I didn’t find any reason to make this explicit in our own code.

If you could make any of the following changes, it would improve matters still:

- Educate the source of your date-time strings to use ISO 8601 format, for example `2020-02-13T16:02:11-05:00`. The format they are using now is a peculiar mix of ISO 8601 and non-ISO, so you and they are really neither getting the advantages of the standard nor the full potential advantages of a more human-readable format. Formatters for ISO 8601 are built into java.time, so using the standard would save us from defining any formatter ourselves. And seconds *are* optional in ISO 8601, so they could still send strings with and without seconds.
- Throw away the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Use `Instant` or another class from java.time and save the conversion that I am doing in the code.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)